# Facing problems while bootup

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking

I am using raspbian on raspberry pi 3.
 I recently changed the network interface from this blog.
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-occidentalis

I made a mistake by deleting the existing lines of the interface file and replacing it with the contents given in the website.

PROBLEM:
  My raspberry pi does the booting but it stops at "systemd-hostnamed.service"

Is there any other alternative other than formatting the SD card?
I would be grateful if someone could help me with this :)

Comment: Can you still log in to that machine to modify the files?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am not able to login. The bootup screen just ends after systemd-hostnamed.service line followed by a lot of lines running on the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not able to mount the card, assuming that you have a Windows PC and that you can put the card in the PC, get this: https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/

Once you install, reboot your computer, and now you can access the Linux FS (ext4). You modify the stuff in the file with the right values, unmount it (from the system tray icon), and put it in your Raspi.

Alternatively, you can use a serial connection if you buy an USB to serial dongle.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try the linux software now. If I have a USB to serial cable, then can I directly run raspbian in my laptop?

Comment: If you have a serial cable, you can connect your Raspi to it on one end and the PC on the other end. make sure to connect the Ground cable, and then TX should go to RX and RX to TX. You can use Putty on the PC to access the console of the Raspi. It's pretty easy really.

Comment: Thank you very much. The linux software helped me solve this problem. Serial cable connection is also very useful since my laptop's lan port has some issues. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

"Is there any other alternative" - YES **DO NOT** follow obsolete tutorials, which even for the obsolete OS would not be best practice. The Adafruit website is full of obsolete information which should have been deleted years ago.

If you did nothing, but enter the WiFi details in the GUI it would have worked.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) to restore to normal settings.

Comment: I am not able to use GUI. Can I still modify on the boot drive which appears when the SD card is connected to the computer?

Comment: @SwethaMurugesan Unfortunately no (unless you have a Linux computer). Modifying the `interfaces` file should NOT stop booting. You can just delete the `interfaces` file.

Comment: I did not modify anything else. Just after I modified the interfaces content, my software connection got interrupted and I am not able to login via Putty or direct connection. The bootscreen just stops loading at systemd-hostnamed.service which made me think that would be something related to network hostname which I modified. *I do have a linux computer. So please guide me so that I do not lose the files on SD card* Thank You :)

Comment: The changes will **TOTALLY** break networking. If you do not have a screen/keyboard it is difficult to advise. The (very confusing) tutorial does not mention any changes to hostname. If you are using a recent Raspbian `ssh` will not work with further configuration, but your original question provides very little information.